# How to send enctype as multipart/form-data in jquery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I know there are many questions about encoding forms as multipart/form-data, but it seems as if most are related to uploading files. *I am not interested in uploading files; nor do I have an actual form.* I simply have a button which calls the following function on click:

```
$.post("http://html5.validator.nu/",
{
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, //this doesn't work !
    content:"<!DOCTYPE html>"//the value of content doesn't matter at the moment
},
function(data){
    print(data);
});
```

The AJAX request executes, but the response from validator.nu (the server) is this:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded not supported. Please use multipart/form-data
```

How can I encode the form using multipart/form-data without actually having a form (just in query)? Is there a line or two that I can add to the request that will do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`"multipart/form-data"` isn't as important to the httpd as it is to the UA. Your browser sees `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and does special handling, the most significant part of which is in the way it shapes the MIME request it sends on to the httpd.

Here are the most relevant parts of an actual `multipart/form-data` HTTP request (captured using [requestb.in](http://requestb.in)):

> Content-Length: 533
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEknFTYZrogVNxemQ
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryEknFTYZrogVNxemQ
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"; filename="foo.png"
>
> Content-Type: image/png
>
> PNG
>
> [PNG data elided]
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryEknFTYZrogVNxemQ
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Submit"
>
> Submit
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryEknFTYZrogVNxemQ--

All of that being said, constructing these MIME parts can be a bit of a PITA, so if you can find a library to do that for you (such as the one suggested by [@Innovation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738558/innovation)) it's probably worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same response while accessing [validator.nu](https://validator.nu/)
with the jQuery.post or $.ajax command and decided 
not to use jQuery after exhausting the various
possible ajax parameter configurations.  It appears
that validator.nu API is more picky than other API
about the format that it receives from jQuery.

The NON jQuery javascript commands that worked for
me were `FormData` and `Append`.

It is also important to note the API requirements
available at:
    
github dot com/validator/validator/wiki

The full code can be found at:
    https://github.com/VividVenturesLLC/validatorNu-JSwebServiceAPI

```
// Following code formatted to fit in the
// response text area, some lines may fail
// syntax check!

//Initialize some variables
//the entire script is written around the API of validator.nu webservice
var validate = 'https://validator.nu';

//  developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData
var formData = new FormData();
//  developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
formData.append('charset','UTF-8');
formData.append('out','json');
formData.append('laxtype','yes');
formData.append('parser','html5');

// developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects
// JavaScript file-like object...
var blob = new Blob([currentPageMarkup], { type: "text/html"});
formData.append("content", blob);

var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
var validationTestResults = null;//expect response from validate webservice
oXHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (oXHR.readyState===1){//OPENED
    console.log("<------- Opened communication at: " + validate +
                " in script: test_valid_html.js -------------->");
}
if (oXHR.readyState===2){//HEADERS_RECEIVED
    console.log("<------- Received AJAX headers from: " + validate +
                " in script: test_valid_html.js -------------->");
}
if (oXHR.readyState===4){//done
    console.log('oXHR.response: ' + oXHR.response);
    //requested a response in JSON format
    validationTestResults = JSON.parse(oXHR.response);
    displayMessages(validationTestResults);//custom display function
    var vtrStatus = getStatus(validationTestResults);
    /* put id=validation_log in a tag in the web page under
       test to output the results because
       remember all the variables lose scope when 
       leaving this function
    */
    //document.getElementById("validation_log").innerHTML=vtrStatus;

    console.log("HTML5 validation status: " + vtrStatus);// this is the message you want
    console.log("<------- Ending AJAX call in script: test_valid_html.js -------------->");
    }
};//end onreadystate change

oXHR.open("POST", validate);
oXHR.send(formData);
```